# Having trouble on this Python homework problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

Question: Write a program to continuously asks the user an exam score given as integer percentages in the range 0 to 100. If a value not in the range is input except for -1, print out an error and prompt the user to try again. Calculate the average of all valid grades input along with the total number of grades in each letter-grade category as follows: 90 to 100 is an A, 80 to 89 is a B, 70 to 79 is a C, 60 to 69 is a D, and 0 to 59 is an F. Use a negative score as a sentinel value to indicate the end of the input. (The negative value is used only to end the loop, so do not use it in the calculations.) For example, if the input is.

```
#Enter in the 4 exam scores
g1=int(input("Enter an exam score between 0 and 100 or -1 to end: "))
g2=int(input("Enter an exam score between 0 and 100 or -1 to end: "))
g3=int(input("Enter an exam score between 0 and 100 or -1 to end: "))
g4=int(input("Enter an exam score between 0 and 100 or -1 to end: "))

total =(g1 + g2 + g3 + g4)

while g1 is range(0,100):
    continue
else:
    print("Sorry",g1,"is not in the range of 0 and 100 or -1. Try again!")

while g2 is range(0,100):
    continue
else:
    print("Sorry",g2,"is not in the range of 0 and 100 or -1. Try again!")

while g3 is range(0,100):
    continue
else:
    print("Sorry",g3,"is not in the range of 0 and 100 or -1. Try again!")

while g4 is range(0,100):
    continue
else:
    print("Sorry",g4,"is not in the range of 0 and 100 or -1. Try again!")

#calculating Average
def calc_average(total):
    return total/4

def determine_letter_grade(grade):
    if 90 <= grade <= 100:
        1 + TotalA
    elif 80 <= grade <= 89:
        1 + TotalB
    elif 70 <= grade <= 79:
        1 + TotalC
    elif 60 <= grade <= 69:
        1 + TotalD
    else:
        1 + TotalF

grade=total
average=calc_average

#printing the average of the 4 scores
print("You entered four valid exam scores with an average of: " + str(average))
print("------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("Grade Distribution:")
print("Number of A's: ",TotalA)
print("Number of B's: ",TotalB)
print("Number of C's: ",TotalC)
print("Number of D's: ",TotalD)
print("Number of F's: ",TotalF)
```

Sample output that I was given:

```
Enter an exam score between 0 and 100 or -1 to end: 88.64 
Enter an exam score between 0 and 100 or -1 to end: 103
Sorry, 103 is not in the range of 0 and 100 or -1. Try Again! 
Enter an exam score between 0 and 100 or -1 to end: 99.10 
Enter an exam score between 0 and 100 or -1 to end: 71.52
Enter an exam score between 0 and 100 or -1 to end: 73
Enter an exam score between 0 and 100 or -1 to end: -1
You entered 4 valid exam scores with an average of 83.07.

Grade Distribution
Number of A’s = 1
Number of B’s = 1
Number of C’s = 2
Number of D’s = 0
Number of F’s = 0
```

Note: This is my first computer science class so I'm sure there is an obvious work around that I am missing but id appreciate any help I can get

Comment: Will there only be 4 exam scores? Or any number of exam scores?

Comment: I'm sorry, but there's many issues with your solution. It appears you haven't quite understood the question or how to write a Python solution for it - for one, your solution assumes there should always be 4 inputs, but what if there are only 3? Or 5? Try to think of the task without code, imagine someone asking you for the scores, adding them up until you tell them you're done and then computing the results. If you describe that process in tiny steps to yourself, you'll be a lot closer to something you should code, instead of coding lines that roughly correspond with the example outputs.

Comment: only 4 exam scores and yea this is the most lost ive been when trying to complete a HW problem.

Comment: That's not a question. Please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) as well as [ask] in general. (I realize OP is deleted, but since I'm voting to close, I want to post my reasoning for reviewers or just in case any other students come across this.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my walk-through explanation:

So, the program is supposed to ask the user what score they got *until* they say they got a score of `-1`, in which after you give them their results. To loop until they give `-1`, we can use a `while` loop:

```
inp = float(input("Enter an exam score between 0 and 100 or -1 to end: ")) # Get input
grades = []
while inp > -1: # Loop until user gives a score of -1
    if inp >= 0 and inp <= 100: # Check if valid grade
        grades.append(inp) # Add grade to grades list
        inp = float(input("Enter an exam score between 0 and 100 or -1 to end: ")) # Ask again
    else:
        print("Sorry", inp, "is not in the range of 0 and 100 or -1. Try again!") # Invalid grade

# ANALYSIS OF GRADES

# Format first line of output - the first str(len(grades)) give the amount of grades they entered,
# and the str(sum(grades) / len(grades)) gives the average of the grades list.
print("You entered", str(len(grades)), "valid exam scores with an average of", str(sum(grades) / len(grades)))

print("Grade Distribution:")
print("Number of A's =", str(sum(90 <= g <= 100 for g in grades)) # I am using a very short notation
print("Number of B's =", str(sum(80 <= g <= 89 for g in grades)) # here - this is basically counting
print("Number of C's =", str(sum(70 <= g <= 79 for g in grades)) # the number of grades that are
print("Number of D's =", str(sum(60 <= g <= 69 for g in grades)) # a valid value based on the checks
print("Number of F's =", str(sum(0 <= g <= 59 for g in grades)) # I am making.
```

Hopefully my comments help you figure out what is happening in my code!

Answer (score 0):

here your problem can be devided into few parts,

1. get number of exam from user
2. get the valid input from user for those exam
3. calculate the average of all exam
4. calculate the grade distribution
5. exit if user input is -1

below code is following all these steps

```
    #calculating Average
    def calc_average(scores):
            return sum(scores)/len(scores)



    grade_dist = {
    (90, 101):'A',
    (80,90):'B',
    (70, 80):'C',
    (59, 70):'D',
    (0,59):'F'
    }

    def get_grade_freq(scores):
        grades = {'A':0, 'B':0, 'C':0, 'D':0, 'F':0}

        for score in scores:
          for k, v in grade_dist.items():
            if score in range(k[0], k[1]):
              grades[v]+=1

        print("Grade distributions")

        for grade, number in grades.items():
            print("Number of {}’s = {}".format(grade, number))



    def get_scores(n):
        scores = []
        cond = True
        while cond and n>0:
          score = int(input("Enter an exam score between 0 and 100 or -1 to end : "))
          if score==-1:
            cond=False
            return -1
          if score not in range(0,101):
              print("Sorry, {} is not in the range of 0 and 100 or -1. Try Again!".format(score))
          if score in range(0,101):
            scores.append(score)
            n-=1
        return scores

    def main():
        n = int(input('total number of exams ' ))

        scores = get_scores(n)
        if scores == -1:
            exit(-1)

        average = calc_average(scores)

        print("You entered {} valid exam scores with an average of {}.".format(n, average))

        get_grade_freq(scores)


    if __name__=='__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have multiple instances of similar things to manipulate (scoring ranges, total counts) you must try to use multi-value structures rather than individual variables.  Python's lists and dictionaries are designed for collecting multiple entries either as a positional list or as a keyed index (dictionary).

This will make your code more generalized. You'll know you're on the right track when you manipulate concepts rather than instances.

For example:

```
grading = [(None,101),("A",90),("B",80),("C",70),("D",60),("F",0)]
scores  = {"A":0, "B":0, "C":0, "D":0, "F":0}
counts  = {"A":0, "B":0, "C":0, "D":0, "F":0}
while True:
    input_value = input("Enter an exam score between 0 and 100 or -1 to end: ")
    value       = int(input_value)
    if value == -1: break
    score = next((s for s,g  in grading if value >= g),None)
    if score is None:
        print("sorry ",input_value," is not -1 or in range of 0...100")
        continue
    scores[score] += value
    counts[score] += 1

inputCount = sum(counts.values())
average    = sum(scores.values())//max(1,inputCount)  
print("")
print("You entered", inputCount, "valid exam scores with an average of: ", average)
print("------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("Grade Distribution:")
for grade,total in counts.items():
    print(f"Number of {grade}'s: ",total)
```

The `grading` list contains pairs of score letter and minimum value (in tuples).  such a structure will allow you to convert the grade values in to score letters by finding the first entry that has a value lower or equal to the input value and use the corresponding letter.

The same list is used to validate the input value by strategically placing a None value after 100 and no value below zero.  The `next()` function will perform the search for you and return None when no valid entry is present.

Your main program loop needs to continue until the input value is -1 but it needs to go through the input at least onces (typical of a repeat-until structure but there is only a `while` in Python).   So the `while` statement will loop forever (i.e. while True) and will need to be arbitrarily broken when the exit condition is met.

To accumulate the scores, a dictionary (`scores`) is better suited than a list because a dictionary will allow you to access instances using a key (the score letter).  This allows you to keep track of multiple scores in a single variable.  The same goes for counting how many of each score were entered.

To get the average at the end, you simply need to sum up the values scores of the `scores` dictionary and divide by the count of of scores you added to the `counts` dictionary.

Finally to print the summary of score counts, you can leverage the dictionary structure again and only write one generalized printing line for all the score letters and totals.

Answer (score -1):

This may work for you:

```
scores = {
    "A": 0,
    "B": 0,
    "C": 0,
    "D": 0,
    "F": 0,
}
total = 0
count = 0

input_value = 0

while (input_value != -1) and (count < 4):
    input_value = int(input("Enter an exam score between 0 and 100 or -1 to end: "))
    if 0 <= input_value <= 100:
        total += input_value
        count += 1
        if input_value >= 90:
            scores["A"] += 1
        elif input_value >= 80:
            scores["B"] += 1
        elif input_value >= 70:
            scores["C"] += 1
        elif input_value >= 60:
            scores["D"] += 1
        else:
            scores["F"] += 1
    else:
        print("Sorry", input_value, "is not in the range of 0 and 100 or -1. Try again!")

print("You entered {} valid exam scores with an average of: {}".format(count, total / count))
print("------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("Grade Distribution:")
print("Number of A's: ", scores['A'])
print("Number of B's: ", scores['B'])
print("Number of C's: ", scores['C'])
print("Number of D's: ", scores['D'])
print("Number of F's: ", scores['F'])
```

Comment: Where is the error correction (to make sure the value is `-1` or between `1-100`)??

Comment: @AyushGarg Cheers for spotting!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. It works at first but after I enter four valid score, it keeps asking more. Not sure what's causing that.

Comment: @Mitchellsullivan the solution can work for any number of entries. If you `while input_value != -1:` to `while (input_value != -1) and (count < 4):`, and a few minor tweaks, this can be limited to 4 entries. I have amended the answer to support up to 4 only

Comment: Why? This code is supposed to be infinite until the user types `-1` in the input!

Comment: Read the comments on this thread, and the comments on the original post. OP stated he wanted only 4 scores entered